# What does "&& n" mean in Kconfig?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile Linux 6.7.2 with support for the x32 ABI and I just can't figure out what this means:

```
Symbol: X86_X32_ABI [=n]
Type  : bool
Defined at arch/x86/Kconfig:3007
  Prompt: x32 ABI for 64-bit mode
  Depends on: X86_64 [=y] && n
  Location:
(3) -> Binary Emulations
      -> x32 ABI for 64-bit mode (X86_X32_ABI [=n])
```

How do I get rid of the `n` in `X86_64 [=y] && n` so that it actually lets me enable this option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The referenced location: [arch/x86/Kconfig:3007](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/Kconfig?h=v6.7.2#n3007):

> ```
> config X86_X32_ABI
>   bool "x32 ABI for 64-bit mode"
>   depends on X86_64
>   # llvm-objcopy does not convert x86_64 .note.gnu.property or
>   # compressed debug sections to x86_x32 properly:
>   # https://github.com/ClangBuiltLinux/linux/issues/514
>   # https://github.com/ClangBuiltLinux/linux/issues/1141
>   depends on $(success,$(OBJCOPY) --version | head -n1 | grep -qv llvm)
>   help
> [...]
> ```

tells that the LLVM variant of objcopy (rather than the "usual" GNU variant) won't convert properly some objects from x86_64 to x86_x32.

So a test is added that depends on the environment to prevent this.

Usual (GNU) `objcopy` would start like:

```
$ objcopy --version | head -n1
GNU objcopy (GNU Binutils for Debian) 2.40
```

LLVM starts like:

```
$ llvm-objcopy --version | head -n1
llvm-objcopy, compatible with GNU objcopy
```

`success` above is a macro [defined like this in Linux sources](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/scripts/Kconfig.include?h=v6.7.2#n18):

> [...]
>
> ```
> if-success = $(shell,{ $(1); } >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "$(2)" || echo "$(3)")
>
> # $(success,<command>)
> # Return y if <command> exits with 0, n otherwise
> success = $(if-success,$(1),y,n)
> ```

All this gets as result `n` when using the LLVM variant of `objcopy`, failing the dependency, and else `y` (which currently should mean using the GNU variant) when evaluating `$(OBJCOPY) --version | head -n1 | grep -qv llvm`.

Told otherwise: currently the x86_x32 ABI support can not be obtained when compiling using Clang/LLVM: use GCC instead.